# Angular Form select- how to show corresponding values from database )postgres, sequelize)?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, forms, select, sequelize.js

I am using Angular, Node.js, Sequelize/Postgres, and have a form (select options form). I am trying to make the option fields depend on each other, so for example when a particular first name is picked, only the corresponding last name is being shown in the other select options field. I don't really know how to do that, only found some similar examples but still don't quite understand how to do that when the values are fetched directly from the database and any help would be appreciated.

Angular factory:

```js
    app.factory('DoctorsFactory', function($http){
    var DoctorsFactory={};

    DoctorsFactory.fetchAll=function(){
        return $http.get('/api/doctors')
            .then(function(docs){
                return docs.data;
            })
       }
        return DoctorsFactory;
    });
```

controller:

```js
    app.controller('AppointmenController', function ($scope, DoctorsFactory) {
     $scope.doctors={};

     DoctorsFactory.fetchAll()
      .then(function(all){
            console.log('bla', all)
            $scope.docs=all;
        })
    });
```

HTML:

```html
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Form control: select</h2>

        <form ng-submit="searchForDoc(doctors)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Firstname</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="doctors.firstname">
                    <option ng-repeat="doc in docs">{{doc.firstname}}</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label for="sel1">Lastname</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="doctors.lastname">
                    <option ng-repeat="doc in docs">{{doc.lastname}}</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label for="sel1">Speciality</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="doctors.speciality">
                    <option ng-repeat="doc in docs">{{doc.speciality}}</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label for="sel1">Department</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="doctors.department">
                    <option ng-repeat="doc in docs">{{doc.department}}</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label for="sel1">School</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="doctors.school">
                    <option ng-repeat="doc in docs">{{doc.school}}</option>
                </select>
                <br>

            </div>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

route:

```js
        router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
        Doctors.findAll({})
        .then(function(alldoctors){
            console.log(alldoctors)
            res.send(alldoctors);
        })
        .catch(next);
    })
```

database model:

```js
    var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

    var db = require('../_db');

    module.exports = db.define('doctors', {
     firstname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
     },
     lastname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
     },
     speciality: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
     },
     department: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
     },
     gender: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
     },
     school: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
     },
     languages:{
         type: Sequelize.STRING
     }
    });
```

Comment: Do you want fo filter lastname options depending on firstname or just show lastname select when firstname is selected?

Comment: i updated my post with the db model. I want it to go both ways for all fields. When fist name is selected, all other fields should be shown wich are related to that firstname, if lets say gender selected is female - then only female first or last names should be shown etc.

Comment: Can you show any example data?

Comment: could be anything (not sure what you means?), lets say: firstname:jessica, lastname:miler, gender, speciality: general, department:general practise, female, school:nyu, language :english, spanish

Comment: I just meant about the structure of the data. The question is how the program has to know what name to match the surname etc. Do you have any tables of relations etc

Comment: Hmm no I dont have tables of relations. I was just filling/seeding the db with data. Shouldnt that be enought without the need of any tables-when I seed the db, all the data is in relation to each other (the firstname, lastname,school etc of one person)

Comment: I know, but J need to know how looks relation in your json to help you.

Comment: I can update with my seed file-is that what you mean? there is no other json